# How can I create a random class that includes an array of number and an array of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string, random

I am doing with a GUI button. When user click it, it will get number or a word randomly. I know how to do it with just numbers,but i don't know how to deal with both words and numbers.

```
int[] numbers = new int[5] { 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 20000};
Random rd = new Random();
int randomIndex = rd.Next(0, 5);
int randomNumber = numbers[randomIndex];
button1.Text = randomNumber.ToString();
```

Comment: Do you have a code that you have done so far? It seems like you need `List<string>` for the random `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution for the `string` would be to create a `List` of `string` you want to display, and then get the random number by `Random.Next()` to display the `string` in that particular `index`. Something like:

```
List<string> words = new List<string> { "Dog", "Cat", "Bird", "Monkey" };
Random rnd = new Random();

... and then in your implementation of the Button Click

int index = rnd.Next(words.Count); //important to limit the random result by the number of the words available
string randomString = words[index]; //Here it is
button1.Text = randomString;
```

Comment: @Donald yup, try it out! ;)

Comment: And since you are going to put it in a button as a text anyway, you can just put numbers in that list AS STRINGS: `new List<string> { "Dog", "Cat", "Bird", "Monkey", "100", "500", "1000" };`

Comment: @diynevala yep, true. Because `Text` is ultimately a `string`. ;)

Comment: @Ian There's even a good reason to use numbers as strings: if you happen to put a number beginning with zero (e.g. zip code 00100) as an integer, it will show up without the zeroes in front (e.g. "100").